# What do 'ssb' and 'sec' mean in gpg's output?

Tags: gnupg

When listing keys with `gpg2 --list-secret-keys`, one is presented with a bunch of lines that begin with `sec` and `ssb`.  What do these mean?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

[According to this website,](https://www.void.gr/kargig/blog/2013/12/02/creating-a-new-gpg-key-with-subkeys/)

```
sec => 'SECret key'
ssb => 'Secret SuBkey'
pub => 'PUBlic key'
sub => 'public SUBkey'
```

[The Debian wiki explains a bit further:](https://wiki.debian.org/Subkeys)

> OpenPGP further supports subkeys, which are like the normal keys,
> except they're bound to a master key pair. A subkey can be used for
> signing or for encryption. The really useful part of subkeys is that
> they can be revoked independently of the master keys, and also stored
> separately from them.
>
> In other words, subkeys are like a separate key pair, but
> automatically associated with your main key pair.
>
> ...
>
> You should keep your private master key very, very safe
>
> ...
>
> Subkeys make this easier: you already have an automatically created encryption
> subkey and you create another subkey for signing, and you keep those
> on your main computer. You publish the subkeys on the normal
> keyservers, and everyone else will use them instead of the master keys
> for encrypting messages or verifying your message signatures.
>
> ...
>
> You will need to use the master keys only in exceptional
> circumstances, namely when you want to modify your own or someone
> else's key.

Comment: I asked about where this might in the official docs at https://dev.gnupg.org/T1563#122298

Comment: Is there further details for `#` and `>`? I believe `#` means not present, and `>` means a stub is present (so the key is on a smartcard) but I cannot find a reference to this.

Comment: @Jared some information about these suffixes is in the [manual](https://www.mankier.com/1/gpg#--list-secret-keys): [quote] A `#` after the initial tags `sec` or `ssb` means that the secret key or subkey is currently not usable.  We also say that this key has been taken offline (for example, a primary key can be taken offline by exporting the key using the command `--export-secret-subkeys`).  A `>` after these tags indicate that the key is stored on a smartcard.  See also `--list-keys`.